# Select By Attributes Based on Unique Value in Shapefile gives ERROR 000840?

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

Using ArcGIS 10.4.1 and Arcpy I am trying to select a shapefile by it attributes and create new feature class based on unique values like

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

def unique_values(table , field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

uniques = unique_values(r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp' , 'fclass')
for unique in uniques:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp', "NEW_SELECTION", " 'fclass' = '"+unique+"' ")
    print (unique)
```

but I am getting this error message

[image]

> Message   File Name   Line    Position     Traceback
>            11
>       SelectLayerByAttribute    C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py 7182
>   ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. The value
>   cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster
>   Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. Failed to
>   execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool Select Layer by Attribute requires a *layer*, not a *feature class*.  A shapefile is a feature class.

You either need to use a layer from the Table of Contents in ArcMap, or create a layer using [Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) tool.

```
for unique in uniques:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'D:/GIS/Roads.shp', 'myLayer')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ('myLayer', "NEW_SELECTION", " 'fclass' = '"+unique+"' ")
    print (unique)
```

Take a look at the documentation for [Select Layer by Attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm)